# 'access is denied' error when using VS 2010, VSTO, Excel 2007 for customized ribbon

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, excel-2007

I'm trying to get a simple ribbon add-in build using VS 2010 and Excel 2007 utilizing VSTO.  I've tried both an Excel Worksheet and Excel Add-in with the same results when I launch Excel (listed below).

I have a larger prototype I'm trying to build, but for now I can't get off the ground with customizing the Excel ribbon.  Has anyone had any luck with building a simple prototype using VS 2010 and Excel 2007?  Did you encounter any Access denied issues when attempting to load in your add-in dll?  Let me stress there is nothing fancy here .. just 2 buttons that don't even do anything at this point (excel doesn't even load the dll, so there's no breakpoints, etc).

I have tried using the 'caspol.exe' tool to grant full trust to my dll, this changed nothing.  I've made sure the folder where the dll is built to has 'Everyone' privileges.  I've tried publishing and installing the add-in, I've also tried just starting it directly from the debugger in VS 2010, same issue over and over again.  I am admin on the server.

Thank you.
Jim

---

Could not load file or assembly 'MyRibbonAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

******* *Exception Text* *********
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyRibbonAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.
File name: 'MyRibbonAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyRibbonAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.
File name: 'MyRibbonAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARGH! It was our virus scanner. I disabled it and things showed up. So many hours wasted. Hopefully this question helps someone else avoid losing time in their life on something stupid